# Adding a google map in a jquery mobile website with geolocation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

i am trying to create a map who show this information :
Ask you for your gps info and after show the direction on a google map from you to a point in database.

My code is working but when i want to integrate it in my jquery mobile webiste it doesn't work.

http://www.etretat.net/office-de-tourisme-etretat/mobile/centrale.php?op=geoloc&id=26

Can someone look what's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask that. Stackoverflow is for help with specific programming problems rather than whole projects.

Comment: Check your console log for errors. I saw two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you have:

```
<div id="maposition">
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"></div> 
  <div id="panel" style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial; font-size: 30px;"></div>
</div>
```

And at various points in the code you have:

```
document.getElementById("maposition").innerHTML = // whatever;
```

Your JS is overwriting the inner content of `#maposition` and deleting the div that's meant to be holding the map in the process :)

Just move `#map` and `#panel` from out of `#maposition`.